# jQuery form validation for a blank field or a field with the wrong format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am looking to have the date validated on submit. Meaning if the value of the input element is blank or if the format is wrong, an error message will appear.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="date-picker.html" id="frmdate" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <p>Start Date: <input type="text" name="txtdate" id="startdate"></p><span id="warning_startdate"></span>
  <p>End Date: <input type="text" name="txtdate" id="enddate"></p><span id="warning_enddate"></span>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

and here is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#startdate, #enddate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});

$('form').on('submit',function(e){
  if(! ( /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.test($('#startdate').val() ) && /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.test($('#enddate').val() ) ) ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("warning_startdate").innerHTML = ('please insert valid date & format');
  }
});
```

Would I need to use a plugin? Is there any way I can do this without a plug in?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HTML did not load, it is here
<form method="get" action="date-picker.html">
Start Date <input type="text" id="startdate">
End Date <input type="text" id="enddate">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive it without plugin by using regular expression in jquery and check for valid dates in form submit event as follow

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$(function() {
  $( "#startdate, #enddate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });     //code indentation
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
   if(! ( /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.test($('#startdate').val() ) && /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.test($('#enddate').val() ) ) )
  {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop form being submitted!
    alert('please insert valid date');
  }
});
```

});

Comment: Thank you, this works. I am now adding a span to my HTML to display the warning msg in the innerhtml instead of an alert. Would this work if I were to have a correct date in one field and an incorrect date in the second?

Comment: you welcome.. :) and for alert you can even use alertify.js or some plugin which is nice to give alert to user or as you said span can also work. :)

Comment: I have used your code to see what would change, and have updated my question. Any take on this? Would I use if/ else statements

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form">
  <p>Start Date <input type="text" id="startdate"></p>
  <p>End Date <input type="text" id="enddate"></p>  
  <input type="submit" id="signup" value="Send">            
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#form').submit(function( event ) { 
  if (($("#startdate").val()) === "" || ($("#enddate").val()) === "") {
    alert('The fields start date and end date cannot be empty. Please enter value.');
    return false;
  } else if(! ( /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.test($('#startdate').val() ) && /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.test($('#enddate').val() ) ) ) {  
    alert('Please insert date in valid format.');
    return false;
  } else {
    $("#form").attr("action", "date-picker.html");
    $( "#form" ).submit();
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/nArYa/86/)

Comment: I have updated the question to now have two seperate error messages display, any help there?

Comment: Make one generic span to display the message, or else you will have to do the validation for each element separately to add innerHTML to specific spans which will include more if-else and increased cyclomatic complexity of the code..

Comment: The one generic one sounds like a good idea. Just out of interest sake, would I use if else statements to do it the other way?

Comment: First if would check for startdate, next if-else for enddate and in each block of code you will have to add innerHTML and error message pertaining to that input field.